# safari 9 delete cookies bug?

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I have a problem, I try to delete cookie use javascript

```
document.cookie = 'my_cookie=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';  

// but my_cookie stille in document.cookie  
console.log(document.cookie);  
// output "my_cookie=;"
```

This is work in safari 8 or chrome or firefox, but in safari 9 is not work. Is bug?
How to delete cookie correctly?

my safari version : 9.0 (10601.1.43)
OS X Yosemite: 10.10.5（14F27)

Today I update safari beta 5 verison: 10601.1.50, 
It still can't delete cookie

```
// this code is work    
document.cookie = "my_cookie =; expires="+new Date('1970').toUTCString()+";"
console.log(new Date('1970').toUTCString()) // Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

I don't know why.... ,But problem is solved.

Comment: it may be security issue for safari 9

Comment: Have you tried changing `GMT` to `UTC`?

Comment: Cookies are still there until the page is loaded again, anyways.

Comment: @PHPglue I try to reload the page(⌘R) , but it still exist

Comment: safari support "max-age" attribute

Comment: I also have the same problem, but your fix didn't work. Are you sure you didn't delete cookies manually from Safari settings @Dian? It makes no sense that the code you said works actually makes any difference.

Comment: Hi @gregers, Maybe you can try to user "document.cookie = "my_cookie =; expires="+new Date().toUTCString()+";""